# Получение индексов в TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть заполненный `TreeView`. Каким образом можно получить индекс выделенного элемента и его родителя сразу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TreeView.SelectedNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode.aspx)

TreeView.SelectedNode.Parent

UPD:

```
TreeView tv = new TreeView();
TreeViewItem selected = (TreeViewItem)tv.SelectedItem;
```

И Parent у [TreeViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.aspx) тоже есть

Comment: я использую WPF, а не WinForms) там то проще

Comment: @blackoverdose, сорри, не заметил. апдейт ответа.

Comment: а каким образом индекс из этого получить?) текст через Header выводится, а index`а нет (Count какой то беспорядочный у каждого элемента)

Comment: @blackoverdose, что-то я из-за жары невнимательный) например, [так][1]
[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398878/getting-the-selectedindex-of-a-child-node-in-a-treeview